# SVG vs UIBezier vs PNG Image on iOS ?

Tags: ios, xcode, svg, uibezierpath

In one of my project I need to reduce the app size. So I was thinking of removing all of **PNG** images from the source and replace them with **SVG** or **UIBezierPath** icons ( created by PaintCode ).

So I was wondering does it help to reduce the app size ?
And also will it also help to improve app performance by any chances ?

Meanwhile, please don't recommend to compress my images, cuz all of them are already compressed to the maximum. I'm just thinking of some other option rather than using png icons.

Comment: I think that in the case of PNG vs SVG that it will depend on the SVG. If it's really complicated, with a bunch of 3rd party namespace garbage filling it, then it may very well be larger than a single PNG. But if its clean, and oftentimes it can replace 3 or more PNGs (1x, 2x, 3x). Also you can make use of vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" to keep the stroke size consistent at different resolutions. No experience with PaintCode.